# DATE formula issue

Tags: formula-field

The below is a part of a formula that i wrote, everything is working fine, except for the below.

My need is, if the " Renewal Month" field ( which is a month picklist field with values as January, february etc). If the month choosen is, less than the current month , it will satisfy certain crtiteria which is working perfect. But if the choosen month is greater than the current month ( i.e i choose : December" but the current month is " November"), where I am getting issue. Then the task date created would be 1/11/2016 i.e current year and minus one month from choosen month ( i.e December).

I wrote it as:

```
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1))
```

But as month is today i have taken, so its giving value as 1/10/2016 , so rather than december taking as november ) today month. So, i changed it as per below , but its showing me syntax error. can anyone plz rectify my below formula. thnx

MONTH(TODAY())-1 To:-

```
CASE( [Lead].Renewal_Month__c, "January",1, "February",2, "March",3, 
 "April",4, "May",5, "June", 6, "July", 7, "August", 8, "September",9, 
  "October", 10, "November", 11, "December", 12,NULL) - 1
```

Comment: The question title should be used to give a summary of the question, please don't include things like "need a fix asap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like error with: [Lead].Renewal_Month__c

-If the date formula field is in the Lead object, then just write: "Renewal_Month__c"

-If it's in child object of Lead, then write: 
"Lead.Renewal_Month__c" (Assume Lead is the field API name in the child object)

Comment: Hi Liron, the field is in Lead object itself. Let me try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Actually below is my whole formula,

Comment: ohh i cant post it, due to char limittion. But it doesnt worked. As i am using processs builder, i am choosing the field an its giving the name as  [Lead].Renewal_Month__c because i have taken the Record type in process builder as " Task", so i.e if my formula work it will create a task with the due date as per my formula. thnx

Comment: If you can follow my this related question link and suggest plz, thanks,   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148233/syntax-error-in-creating-a-formula-need-to-fix-asap