# Syntax error in Creating a formula

Tags: formula-field

My below formula is showing a syntax error, Can anyone plz suggest where its gone wrong in syntax. I am using it in process builder.

I have a month picklist field in lead " renewal month", if the month choosen is less than current month, the task due date is next year, previous month. But if my choosen month is greater than current month (i.e now november & if i choose December), then it should be current year and previous month.
Now all is perfect , only showing issue in second part i.e if my month is greater than the current month ( i.e choosen is December). , So most probably issue is my last part of the formula, for me seems its all perfect, can anyone plz try to figure out where i went wrong. thanks

```
IF(
CASE( [Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4,     
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,NULL)< MONTH(TODAY()),
IF(TEXT([Lead].Renewal_Month__c)="January",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,1), 
DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,CASE([Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4, 
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,NULL)-1,1)),

DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), CASE([Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4, 
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,NULL)-1, 1))
```

Comment: How is the different than your other question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148230/date-formula-issue-need-to-fix-asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried same formula in my org. it saved without error but the small changes on your formmula.
1. [Lead.field] - u can use directly field no need of object.

```
IF(
CASE(Month__c ,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4,     
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,0)< MONTH(TODAY()),
IF(TEXT(Month__c)="January",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,1), 
DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,CASE(Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4, 
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,0)-1,1)),

DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), CASE(Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4, 
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,NULL)-1, 1))
```

Comment: Hi Shravan. thanks. have you tried in the process builder ?

Comment: when i used the process builder , i taken the record type as " Task" in teh immmediate action and the initial object aas " Lead", so when i am putting the formula and choosing from teh insert field its taking automatically the Lead object.

Comment: If i dont take the lead object , its showing me as " The formula expression is invalid: Field Renewal_Month__c does not exist. Check spelling."